# Pandas: Select rows up to last occurrence of value relative to another row

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following if statement:

```
if day_csv['Day of Week'].iloc[-7] != 'Monday':
```

I would like to select all rows up to the Monday *before* iloc[-7] (until the bottom of the dataframe).

How can I go about doing so?

The dataframe looks like:

| Date | Day of Week | Several columns of numbers |

Thank you for your help! I didn't find any duplicates, sorry if this one is a bit simple.

**Edit:**

I actually changed my mind about how I was going to do this - easier to just show the last 8-14 days or so. For the sake of learning/answering the original question, though:

Here is some example data:

| Date | Day of Week | Offer | Answer | ... | Last Week Same Day | Percent Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-08 | Friday | 4821.0 | 2091.0 | ... | 1114.0 | -0.046474 |
| 2021-10-09 | Saturday | 4821.0 | 2091.0 | ... | 121.0 | 0.153086 |
| 2021-10-10 | Sunday | 4821.0 | 2091.0 | ... | 4525.0 | NaN |
| 2021-10-11 | Monday | 8424.0 | 2095.0 | ... | 9553.0 | 0.26489 |
| 2021-10-12 | Tuesday | 8432.0 | 2095.0 | ... | 9235.0 | 0.3858 |
| 2021-10-13 | Wednesday | 4821.0 | 2091.0 | ... | 1114.0 | -0.046474 |
| 2021-10-14 | Thursday | 4821.0 | 2091.0 | ... | 121.0 | 0.153086 |
| 2021-10-15 | Friday | 4821.0 | 2091.0 | ... | 4525.0 | NaN |
| 2021-10-16 | Saturday | 8424.0 | 2095.0 | ... | 9553.0 | 0.26489 |
| 2021-10-17 | Sunday | 8432.0 | 2095.0 | ... | 9235.0 | 0.3858 |
| 2021-10-18 | Monday | 8432.0 | 2095.0 | ... | 9235.0 | 0.3858 |
| 2021-10-18 | Tuesday | 8432.0 | 2095.0 | ... | 9235.0 | 0.3858 |

I've made the numbers up, as they're unimportant. The expected output of the operation would be a selection of the last 7 rows if the 7th row is a Monday, or all the rows beyond to an occurrence of a Monday before that. So, for here, we would have these rows selected:

| Date | Day of Week | Offer | Answer | ... | Last Week Same Day | Percent Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-11 | Monday | 8424.0 | 2095.0 | ... | 9553.0 | 0.26489 |
| 2021-10-12 | Tuesday | 8432.0 | 2095.0 | ... | 9235.0 | 0.3858 |
| 2021-10-13 | Wednesday | 4821.0 | 2091.0 | ... | 1114.0 | -0.046474 |
| 2021-10-14 | Thursday | 4821.0 | 2091.0 | ... | 121.0 | 0.153086 |
| 2021-10-15 | Friday | 4821.0 | 2091.0 | ... | 4525.0 | NaN |
| 2021-10-16 | Saturday | 8424.0 | 2095.0 | ... | 9553.0 | 0.26489 |
| 2021-10-17 | Sunday | 8432.0 | 2095.0 | ... | 9235.0 | 0.3858 |
| 2021-10-18 | Monday | 8432.0 | 2095.0 | ... | 9235.0 | 0.3858 |
| 2021-10-18 | Tuesday | 8432.0 | 2095.0 | ... | 9235.0 | 0.3858 |

Comment: Is possible add some data sample and expected ouput?

Comment: Answer was edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit last 6 rows (if possible 7th is `Monday` by indexing, get original values filled by `NaN`s by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html)), compare for `Monday` by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) with cumulative sum and last filter by maximal values:

```
s = day_csv['Day of Week'].iloc[:-6].reindex(day_csv.index).eq('Monday').cumsum()


df = day_csv[s.eq(s.max())]
print (df)
          Date Day of Week   Offer  Answer  ...  Last Week Same Day  \
3   2021-10-11      Monday  8424.0  2095.0  ...              9553.0   
4   2021-10-12     Tuesday  8432.0  2095.0  ...              9235.0   
5   2021-10-13   Wednesday  4821.0  2091.0  ...              1114.0   
6   2021-10-14    Thursday  4821.0  2091.0  ...               121.0   
7   2021-10-15      Friday  4821.0  2091.0  ...              4525.0   
8   2021-10-16    Saturday  8424.0  2095.0  ...              9553.0   
9   2021-10-17      Sunday  8432.0  2095.0  ...              9235.0   
10  2021-10-18      Monday  8432.0  2095.0  ...              9235.0   
11  2021-10-18     Tuesday  8432.0  2095.0  ...              9235.0   

    Percent Diff  
3       0.264890  
4       0.385800  
5      -0.046474  
6       0.153086  
7            NaN  
8       0.264890  
9       0.385800  
10      0.385800  
11      0.385800
```